# Клик по разным частям одного изображения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

есть прямоугольное изображение с тэгом img (для примера w: 300, h:50), оно находиться в div (прижато к правому краю div`a).  Изображение - это меню, т.е. нарисованы иконки. Требуется (с помощью jquery), чтоб при клике на иконку (т.е. прямоугольная обаласть) срабатывала относящаяся к ней ссылка. Координаты изображения изменяются в зависимости от ширины экрана. Подскажите, как реализовать.

Comment: кто поставил минус не знаю но задача на самом деле интересная , есть map generator в нём можно на img отметить участки  и присвоить им по клику событие ...событие может быть любое так же открыть url ....это же самое умеет svg

Comment: Жаль, что отметить, как ответ можно только 1 вариант. Все предложенное отвечает моим требованиям. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.img-menu {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .link {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
 }
 
 #link1 {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
  #link2 {
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
  #link3 {
   top: 50%;
   left: 0;
 }
  #link4 {
   top: 50%;
   right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="img-menu">
  <img src="https://postio.ru/pub/img/articles/4/2.png">
  <a class="link" id="link1" href="/1"></a> 
  <a class="link" id="link2" href="/2"></a> 
  <a class="link" id="link3" href="/3"></a> 
  <a class="link" id="link4" href="/4"></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но данный вариант, в моем случае вряд ли подойдет.

Comment: @medvedev почему?

Comment: Не буду утверждать (надо тестить), но подозреваю, что при масштабировании самого изображения и/или окна (в следствии чего опять же может масштабироваться изображение), ссылки могут не срабатывать там где надо, т.е. смещаться, но возможно я заблуждаюсь. Завтра буду проверять, все предложенные варианты.

Comment: @medvedev нет, ссылки смещаться не будут=)

Comment: Зря сомневался в твоем варианте! Все работает, как надо, минимум кода и масштабируемо. Спасибо!

Comment: @medvedev не за что ;)

Answer (score 3):

Используется плагин [jQuery-rwdImageMaps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

Пример 1

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();

  $('area').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
img[usemap] {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/1.6/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>

<h1>Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin</h1>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x50" width="300" height="50" usemap="#imageMap" alt="">
<map name="imageMap">
  <area alt="topLeft" title="topLeft" href="#topLeft" coords="150,25,0,0" shape="rect">
  <area alt="bottomLeft" title="bottomLeft" href="#bottomLeft" coords="150,50,0,25" shape="rect">
  <area alt="topRight" title="topRight" href="#topRight" coords="300,25,150,0" shape="rect">
  <area alt="bottomRight" title="bottomRight" href="#bottomRight" coords="300,50,150,25" shape="rect">
 </map>
```

Пример 2

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.block__inner {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 16.67%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.block__img,
.block__link>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block__link {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 8.335%;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.block__link>span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block__link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/50/animals" class="block__img" alt="">

    <a href="#" class="block__link" title="Top Left"><span>Top Left</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="block__link" title="Top Right"><span>Top Right</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="block__link" title="Bottom Left"><span>Bottom Left</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="block__link" title="Bottom Right"><span>Bottom Right</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В каком плане живой? Нет исходного кода и примера, что и как. Поэтому демо вариант.

Comment: Есть другая идея. Скоро оформлю

Comment: Спасибо! Прямо сейчас к сожалению нет возможности затестить на своих данных, но судя по коду - это то что надо. Завтра проверю, лайк сразу ставлю!

Comment: @Максим Ленский - добавил вариант 2

Comment: найти соотв. координаты и испол. 1 вариант

Comment: Эти варианты тоже хороши, но воспользовался ответом @Ruslan Mirzapulatov. Но 1-ый пример меня тоже очень заинтересовал, в другом проекте обязательно использую. Спасибо!